# Nest ggplot histograms per variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to create a data frame where I summarize values like number of observations, mean and median, and I want to nest its ggplot histograms. For this, I will use the iris dataset.

This is my first attempt:

```
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  summarise(obs = n(),
            mean = round(mean(Values),2),
            median = round(median(Values),2))
```

So it gives me:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Vars           obs  mean median
  <chr>        <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Petal.Length   150  3.76   4.35
2 Petal.Width    150  1.2    1.3 
3 Sepal.Length   150  5.84   5.8 
4 Sepal.Width    150  3.06   3
```

This is the expected table:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Vars           obs  mean median plot
  <chr>        <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <list>
1 Petal.Length   150  3.76   4.35 <gg>
2 Petal.Width    150  1.2    1.3  <gg>
3 Sepal.Length   150  5.84   5.8  <gg>
4 Sepal.Width    150  3.06   3    <gg>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(metrics = lapply(data, function(df) df %>% summarise(obs = n(), mean = mean(Values), median = median(Values))),
         plots = lapply(data, function(df) df %>% ggplot(aes(Values)) + geom_histogram()))
```

Almost there, I see this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Vars [4]
  Vars         data               metrics          plots 
  <chr>        <list>             <list>           <list>
1 Sepal.Length <tibble [150 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 3]> <gg>  
2 Sepal.Width  <tibble [150 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 3]> <gg>  
3 Petal.Length <tibble [150 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 3]> <gg>  
4 Petal.Width  <tibble [150 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 3]> <gg>
```

But I don't know how to see the expected tibble with the obs, mean, median and plots columns without the data and metrics columns. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `cur_data()` in `summarise` and get the output in a `list` by wrapping

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
out <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  summarise(obs = n(),
            mean = round(mean(Values),2),
            median = round(median(Values),2), 
    plots = list(ggplot(cur_data(), aes(Values)) + geom_histogram()))
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Vars           obs  mean median plots 
  <chr>        <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <list>
1 Petal.Length   150  3.76   4.35 <gg>  
2 Petal.Width    150  1.2    1.3  <gg>  
3 Sepal.Length   150  5.84   5.8  <gg>  
4 Sepal.Width    150  3.06   3    <gg>
```

Comment: According to the documentation, `cur_data()` gives the current data for the current group. I didn't know that function, thank you very much @akrun! Have a great day!

Comment: By the way, my method of using nests was a little convoluted, wasn't it?

Comment: @Alexis With `nest_by`, you can get the same output, but then, have to extract those `obs`, `mean`, `median` etc

Comment: Hi @akrun, I want to learn how to extract those values. I think I'll post another question on that issue. Thank you for your time and patience answering this doubt!